# Find hotspot password in Windows 10 using command line or registry editor

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking

I'm currently trying to find the hotspot password on my school-issue laptop, the only issue is they've blocked off the network section of windows settings so people can't remove the firewall they have set up. I obviously don't have administrator access, but I don't need to change anything, I just need to get the hotspot password. If there's a registry key containing the password, that would be the easiest way to find it, but PowerShell and CMD methods would also work, as long as they don't require admin access. As to why I'm doing this, the school is a concrete block and data connection inside the school is spotty at best. I don't really care about the firewall, since I have multiple accessible VPNs and proxies on my phone. If possible, USB tethering is also an option, though I don't know is I can give my phone connection via my laptop. The laptop is a Dell Latitude 3120 running Windows 10 Education, (Build 19043, in case you need it for some reason) and my phone is a Pixel 3a XL running Android 12 on the latest security patch.

**Edit:**
They've implemented a sort of program whitelist, so I can't install or run custom software.

Comment: Try https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/view-windows-10-wifi-passwords.html

Comment: I'm afraid they implement a program whitelist, and as such I am unable to run custom software, so no-go.